# How to achieve edge-depth effect on Android

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to achieve 3d edge effect on android listview (or gridview). See the attached picture you can see the depth on edges (the vertical line in middle of image). Can i achieve the same effect with combination of different strokes? I have tried using 2 layers with strokes of width 1 & 3, but not getting required effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it. Two consecutive lines will give this effect. The first one should be darker then background and second one should be lighter then background. For pop-up effect, just reverse the order (lighter first and then darker)